# Required information for configure application with Azure AD SSO

Tags: azure-active-directory

We required to configure our application SSO with azure AD. Developer asking below information for configure SSO, could your please tell me where i find these information in Azure AD.

What we will need from the SSO Provider are the following details:

1. Issuer URL
2. Sign in URL
3. X.509 Certificate

Thanks in advance,
Rocky

Comment: What protocol are you using for SSO? Azure AD supports OpenID Connect, WS-Federation and SAML2.

Comment: We are using SAML

Comment: @RockyMondal Have you gone through?  : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/configure-saml-single-sign-on  or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/single-sign-on-saml-protocol